# How to adjust subtitle font size in Swift macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui, subtitle, vlckit

Using VLCKit I am able to display subtitles by setting the current video subtitle index. But I can't find an option in the documentation that allows to change the font and font size. So I have know idea how to increase or decrease the font size.

```
import VLCKit

let player = VLCMediaPlayer()
let media = VLCMedia!

media = VLCMedia(url: mediaURL)
player.media = media
player.play()

//Set subtitle
player.currentVideoSubTitleIndex = 1

//Change font size
??
```

EDIT (March 13, 00:22)

```
player = VLCMediaPlayer(options: ["--sub-text-scale=10"])!
```

This changed the font size, but can this also be done while the video is playing or would that require re-initializing the player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a private API on VLCMediaPlayer called "setTextRendererFontSize:(NSNumber *)fontSize" with further methods allowing font changes, boldness and color to be changed while the video plays. However, this is currently compiled for iOS only. I'll do a quick change for the 3.6.0 update to have it available on macOS and tvOS, too.

For version 4 of VLCKit, we plan to have a public API for this. The option you found is also legitimate but as you already noticed requires a restart of playback.

Comment: May I compliment you and your team for the amazing job you are already doing. Also for taking the time to answer this question on stack overflow. Hope you have a lovely day. I will wait patiently for 3.6.0 update.